# Sort opencart specials at the end of the product categories

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I've got a webshop with a pretty high number of products and a pretty high number of specials. In every product category, the specials are scattered among the normal priced products and this makes it one big mess. Is there some way to sort all the specials at the back of the category? I also have my specials in the seperate 'specials category' so in all the other categories I would like the start with the normal priced products. Any ideas?

I found a tutorial on how to sort by subcategories, but that didn't get me any further.

Thanks!

Comment: If You look into `catalog/model/product.php::getProducts()` You can find this line: `$sql .= " ORDER BY (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END)";` - this should kick You on the right way.

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse there is, but you need to work with you tpl a bit in category.tpl, the thing you have to do is simply when `foreach($products as $product)` is called specify an if clause right afterwards like `if($product['special'])` and then pass these data in an array like `$special_products`, then afterwards at the end of foreach cycle add on new cycle `foreach($special_products as $special_product)`, now i am too lazy to wright this piece of code, but i think if you follow the guidelines you can do it on your own without any problems.
If you need further assistance i could gladly help you.

Comment: I wouldn't use this approach from many reasons. Speed, resources, handling of data in template which only should display them, missing logic...